# SUM using different criteria/conditions in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm running a summer camp this year and parents who sign up more than one child get a daily discount (10$/child/day). However, I am not certain how total it when a parent fills in the Google Form with more than one child. They can also chose the weeks that they want to attend, so a generalized equation can't be created (to my knowledge).

I can use the SUM and IF functions but I am unsure how to calculate the different the discount if more than one child is signed up:

My formula right now is for one child:

```
=SUM(IF(B3="Yes";145;0);IF(C3="Yes";155;0);
IF(D3="Yes";124;0);IF(F3="Yes";155;0);
IF(G3="Yes";155;0);IF(H3="Yes";124;0))
```

*Note some weeks are different prices*

Here is a link to the sheet: https://goo.gl/7nUizc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, but I am certain there is a simpler way! I put the whole thing in an if statement, so if the second child option is blank use one calculation if it's not blank use a different set of numbers:

```
=IF(E4="";SUM(IF(B4="Yes";145;0);IF(C4="Yes";155;0);IF(D4="Yes";124;0);
IF(F4="Yes";155;0);IF(G4="Yes";155;0);IF(H4="Yes";124;0));
SUM(IF(B4="Yes";145;0);IF(C4="Yes";145;0);IF(D4="Yes";114;0);
IF(F4="Yes";145;0);IF(G4="Yes";145;0);IF(H4="Yes";116;0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your formula is confusing (in fact, I think there's a mistake with the number). The best way is to use [`sumif()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583?hl=en) and put the rates in a separate sheet so you don't make mistake

You need to change the formula to determining # of children to `and(len(trim(A2));len((trim(E2))))` so that values like "  " (with only space inside) will be ignored.

Your sheet has been modified.